# Web Scraping with Nokogiri::HTML and Ruby - Output to CSV issue

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, scrape

I have a script that scrapes HTML article pages of a webshop. I'm testing with a set of 22 pages of which 5 article pages have a product description and the others don't.

This code puts the right info on screen:

```
if doc.at_css('.product_description')
  doc.css('div > .product_description > p').each do |description|
    puts description
  end
  else
    puts "no description"
end
```

But now I'm stuck on how to get this correctly to output the found product descriptions to an array from where I'm writing them to a CSV file.

Tried several options, but none of them works so far.
If I replace the `puts description` for `@description << description.content`, then all the descriptions of the articles end up in the upper lines in the CSV although they do not belong to the articles in that line.

When I also replace "no description" for `@description =  "no description"` then the first 14 lines in my CSV recieve 1 letter of "no description" each. Looks funny, but it is not exactly what I need.

If more code is needed, just shout!

This is the CSV code I use in the script:

```
    CSV.open("artinfo.csv", "wb") do |row|
    row << ["category", "sub-category", "sub-sub-category", "price", "serial number",  "title", "description"]
    (0..@prices.length - 1).each do |index|
    row << [
            @categories[index], 
            @subcategories[index], 
            @subsubcategories[index], 
            @prices[index],
            @serial_numbers[index], 
            @title[index],
            @description[index]]
     end 
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us your CSV code as well?

Comment: Part of the confusion is calling your CSV object `row`

Comment: Don't understand, the other data display correct in the csv file... only the description acts weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your data isn't lined up properly. If it were you should be able to do:

```
CSV.open("artinfo.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["category", "sub-category", "sub-sub-category", "price", "serial number",  "title", "description"]
  [@categories, @subcategories, @subsubcategories, @prices, @serial_numbers, @title, @description].transpose.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end 
end
```

Comment: That gives me a can't convert string to array on the csv << [category etc.,etc. line which I should look into

Comment: If I were you I would find a better way to iterate. It doesn't make sense to put all the prices in one array, all the titles on another etc.

Comment: With this last tip and a good look at the code I managed to fix my problem, thnx!